# execute request without adding listner

Tags: android, datadroid

In DataDroid Library, for executing request we use 
`execute(request, listner)`

**Is there any method for executing request without using listner?**

```
I need to send Information to server and for which the response is not related to    user.So, I will handle error and success case in Operation.
I dont want to override methods : 
onRequestFinished(),
onRequestConnectionError(),
onRequestDataError()
as there is no UI updation.
```

Answer (score 0):

[`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) should work for you. You can do whatever you want in doInBackground, and return the result in onPostExecute, and you *can* manipulate the UI from there if need be. Otherwise it is just a background thread that communicates with your server.

Comment: Your answer is not related to my question. Thanks for your response

Comment: You said nothing more than communication between android and a server, so I suggested the natural way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution : execute(request, null).